# WPML Navigation Menu Location Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

### Context

I was trying to add custom language switching links in the navigation. The problem is I have two menu location `header-main` and `footer-main` (These are the menu slugs). But I only want language links in the `header-main` menu.

Currently the wordpress callback `wp_nav_menu_items` works fine, but it will add the links processed to all the menu locations. Here is the working code for it:

```
function icl_post_languages() {
    return icl_get_languages('skip_missing=1');
}

function get_translation_navigation() {
    $nav = '';
    $lang_nav = icl_post_languages();
    if (count($lang_nav) > 0) {
        foreach ($lang_nav as $item) {
            $nav .= '<li>';
            $nav .= '<a href="' . $item['url'] . '">' . $item['native_name'] . '</a>';
            $nav .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    return $nav;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_translation_navigation');

function add_translation_navigation($menu) {
    $language_nav = get_translation_navigation();
    $menu = $menu . $language_nav;
    return $menu;
}
```

### The Issue

But when I change the wordpress filter to:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_header-main_items', 'add_translation_navigation');
```

So, that the filter is applied to only `header-main` menu. It works and fires the filter when current language is `English`, when the language is switched to `Arabic` it doesn't fires the filter.

Also, there are two separate menus, one for `Arabic` and one for `English`, but location of both is same i.e. `header-main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but it looks like you're confusing *theme locations* and *menu slugs* regarding the `wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items` filter. You could try for example:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_translation_navigation', 99, 2 );

function add_translation_navigation( $menu, $args )
{
    if( 'header-main' == $args->theme_location )
        $menu .= get_translation_navigation();

    return $menu;
}
```

to check for the specific `header-main` theme location.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think WordPress handles two different menus with the same menu slug as you describe here. Therefore it only applies your script to the first of the two menus.

I would rather advise you to alter the menu slugs to something like:

- `header-main-english`
- `header-main-arabic`

and then just simply add:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_header-main-english_items', 'add_translation_navigation');
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_header-main-arabic_items', 'add_translation_navigation');
```

Comment: I have only defined one menu location for header menu i.e. 'header-main' .. WPML picks it up itself and separates the menus for arabic and english (or for number of languages activated) ..